# What is a Java microservice

Tags: java, microservices

I been searching on the web, but I'm a little confused on what exactly is a Java microservice. I mean I know what a web service is, and I'm told that a microservice is the following per wiki:

> In computing, microservices is a software architecture style in which complex applications are composed of small, independent processes communicating with each other using language-agnostic APIs.

and the properties of a microservice are:

> Properties of microservices architecture:
>
> It's a kind of architecture The services are easy to replace Services
> are organized around capabilities, e.g. user interface front-end,
> recommendation, logistics, billing, etc Services can be implemented
> using different programming languages, databases, hardware and
> software environment, depending on what fits best Architectures are
> symmetrical rather than hierarchical (producer - consumer)

I need a concrete Java example to understand how I can make a microservice.  Does anyone have a example you could provide?

Comment: Try to imagine how the Unix OS works.  There is a Kernel that is the main process controlling everything.  But everything that makes the OS actually DO anything is all the little programs that make up the system.  There is a separate, tiny program, that runs every aspect of what the system does.

Comment: thats a nice analogy but in java web code would you say that a microservice could be a api call ? Lets say i had one web service to get user accounts and then i had another 'microservice' web api  to get the address and phone numbers of the user account and return it back to the first call, would that count as a microservice ?

Comment: I would say so.  Anything that is sorta sitting in the background waiting to be given an instruction, and otherwise keeps quite, would qualify.  As long as it's not part of the main thread, taking up memory when it's not in use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A microservice is exactly like its name suggests. It's a tiny service that performs a very simple function.

So yes, in terms of code, you're probably looking at a REST service. Note that any other API style would work. It doesn't have to be REST, however it must be **language agnostic** for you to draw all the benefits.

But the idea is bigger than that. The idea behind it is that they are very specialized and there's no big business workflow attached to they. For example, if you have a service that processes payments, then writes an audit log, then notifies the customer. I wouldn't count that as a microservice. Writing an audit log, that'd probably be a microservice, notifying the customer too, processing the credit card as well. Your system would coordinate that business workflow (the 3 steps mentioned above) by calling the 3 necessary microservices. So your system is a coordinator and you don't worry about implementing the business functions.

Microservices don't try to think too much, they just do as they're told, but they do it quickly.

So in short. Take a very simple business function, put a REST API in front of it. And you have a microservice.

There are several **interesting properties** with microservices:

1. They can be deployed independently. That's nice because you can deploy pieces of your app without taking everything down all at once.
2. They can run in their own silo. So if you have a microservice that is very memory hungry, it can be deployed on a separate server so it doesn't affect the rest of your system.
3. They can use different technology. You may have microservices in Java, some on .Net
4. They keep dependencies in check. Developers have a tendency to bleed dependencies from one component to the next when they live together. Here you can't.

But you should also consider some **drawbacks**

1. It's a lot harder to maintain a consistent transaction across all these calls. If you need to roll back, you'll need JTA to rollback all the REST calls. That can be a pain and doesn't perform very well in my experience.
2. Tracking a transaction through the system in order to troubleshoot can be pretty rough if you don't have consistent logging and a consistent transaction id
3. It might get tricky to find where a defect was introduced if the ground is constantly shifting due to deployments that may have side effects.
4. Obviously all these REST calls can stack up to be pretty expensive. I'm not necessarily talking about the transport since it's likely all your microservices would live in the same data center. But every time you make a call over the network, you have to marshal/unmarshal your data and that could quickly get expensive CPU-wise.

Comment: @Gimby Fair enough. Although "micro" does imply a smaller service (from a function perspective, not actual size in code), that's the point I was trying to make. And nowhere do I say it's tied to REST, other than mentioning that one typical implementation is using REST. That's backed by http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html, second paragraph. It's not a constraint, just a typical use.

Comment: Added details to be more explicit

Answer (score 2):

You can check this:
https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka

This example is based on the following services:

**Netflix Eureka :**

Eureka is a REST (Representational State Transfer) based service that is primarily used in the AWS cloud for locating services for the purpose of load balancing and failover of middle-tier servers.

Eureka is just a Service Registry holding all started service instance severname and port details.

**Netflix Zuul :**

Zuul is an edge service that provides dynamic routing, monitoring, resiliency, security, and more.

It is the endpoint for microservice clients. All other service instances are secured in secured box whereas Zuul is exposed to clients which intercepts all client requests.

**Netflix Ribbon:**

Ribbon is a Inter Process Communication (remote procedure calls) library with built in software load balancers. The primary usage model involves REST calls with various serialization scheme support.

Ribbon works in conjunctions with Zuul, uses plenty of algorithms to elect the best performing service node to serve the requests when N number of microservice instances are running.

In simple words, Zuul intercepts client requests and based on the request URL Zuul finds the ip and port of Microservice instance by Using Eureka service discovery. Ribbon elects the best service node to service the request and then from Zuul request is routed to the respective microservice instance.

**Advantage from my project perspective:**

We can add or remove 'N' number of service nodes based on the network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some concrete examples of microservices written in Java. These microservices are educational by design so hopefully that means you should be able to follow along.

It is not recommended to write a Java microservice from scratch as there are plenty of frameworks that can accelerate your development. The two most popular Java frameworks for microservice development are Spring Boot and Dropwizard.

The [feed3 project](https://github.com/gengstrand/clojure-news-feed/tree/master/server/feed3) implements a rudimentary polyglot persistent news feed microservice using Dropwizard.

The [feed8 project](https://github.com/gengstrand/clojure-news-feed/tree/master/server/feed8) implements the same feature identical microservice using Spring Boot.

There is even a [Spring Boot vs Dropwizard article](http://glennengstrand.info/software/performance/springboot/dropwizard) that analyzes the differences.

Answer (score 1):

- Microservice architecture means multiple smaller applications that can communicate with each other using a light weight protocols like HTTP.
- Monolithic approach was replaced by a microservice.
- Lets begin with monolithic approach. Imagine a Facebook app, where we can post, chat, it has login page etc. All this comes under a single code base and it becomes difficult to manage. If a small bug is detected the whole application may crash down. Also if we want to add a single functionality in login page we will have to redeploy the whole application once its done.
- Now let's imagine the same scenario with microservices. Now in microservice we will have multiple small applications - one for login, one for messaging, one for posing the content, etc. These applications are loosely coupled with each other. They can communicate with each other through REST APIs. Now if one application is down it wont affect the other applications. We can easily add any functionality and deploy only that specific code, no need to deploy the whole application. We can easily use different technologies for building different microservices.